# How do you refer to a member of a biological taxon in the singular?

Tags: latin, grammatical-number

If I wish to refer to, say, an Owl in the more generic form as a member of the biological order Strigiformes, what is the correct modification of the apparently plural word into a singular form?

For instance:

> Upon entering the forest, Jonothan was immediately assaulted by an angry [singular strigiformes].

Or:

> The Manduca Sexta is a [singular lepidoptera] which feeds on a [singular solanaceae] during the larval phase, normally a Tobacco plant.

Comment: Why would you not use the singular form of the Latin word? They are not, generally, considered English words, but remain Latin words, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends:

- One of the *strigiformes* is a *strigiform*.  Or an owl.
- One of the *lepidoptera* is a *lepidopter*:

  - 1881 Elwes tr. *De S. Pinto’s How I crossed Afr.* I. v. 120 ― This gigantic **lepidopter**, when young, feeds upon the grasses.
- One of the *solanaceae* is a *solanacean*.   Or a nightshade.

Comment: Correct. And a strigiform (a member of Strigiformes), is an avis or bird (a member of Aves), an animal (a member of Animalia), and a eukaryote (a member of Eukaryota).

Comment: Yeah. You have to learn to recognize Latin and Greek plural markings (_-es, -a, -ae, ..._) and generate either their singular or an acceptable adjectival noun (like _solanacean_ from _solanacea_). Any taxonomist can point you at manuals for naming conventions; there are a number, varying somewhat by phylum and kingdom, and occasionally by lower taxa.